# ValueError in computing precision using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score

precision_score(expected, predicted)
```

where expected is `array([ 4.,  3.])`

and predicted is `array([ 2.,  4.])`

I get the foll. error: `*** ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array([ 2.,  3.,  4.])`

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `average` parameter for *multiclass* labels.

Else you would need to set `pos_label` as one of the class labels in both arrays i.e. 2, 3 or 4:

```
>>> # score for all classes
>>> precision_score(expected, predicted, average=None)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])

>>> # score for each class
>>> precision_score(expected, predicted, pos_label=2)
0.0
>>> precision_score(expected, predicted, pos_label=3)
0.0
>>> precision_score(expected, predicted, pos_label=4)
0.0
```

Reference:
[`sklearn.metrics.precision_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html)